# Passing a list of parameters to SQL query is gives Missing binding variable error in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

Hello I am using Oracle ManagedDataAccess in my application. I want to pass a list of names to my database query. After referring to few stackoverflow answers I wrote this.

But it is giving me Binding variable error. Can someone help me to find out what change I should make to pass the list as parameter to query.

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    try
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE NAME IN :nameList";
        string[] paramNames = _names.Select((s, i) => ":nameList" 
                                           +i.ToString()).ToArray();
                            
        for (int i = 0; i < paramNames.Length; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramNames[i], _names[i]);
        }
        DbDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: The only parameter that query wants is `:nameList` - it doesn't want `:nameList0`, `:nameList1`, etc; you should be adding a single parameter with name `:nameList` here...? (and setting `cmd.BindByName=true;`, probably)

Comment: I guess according to Oracle SQL Syntax that should have been `... WHERE NAME IN ( _mnemoncis[0], _mnemonics[1], ... )` , of course replaced by the actual values ... so why did you choose this way?

Comment: My list of names , _names (Sorry I have changed the list name) will be of variable length. So I want to have a list there ,something like :  WHERE NAME IN (_names)